# php on submit update database in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, foreach

the problem is with this that when to use the select with the options in the change_admin form that it will not change for only the product it should but also for al the other products in the same store and i dont want that. i worked for 4 hours on it but i cant find the solution.

here is the idea(i know the code is not code but it gives the idea of what i want to achieve and how):

```
    <form method="post">
    <select name="store">
        <option value="1">amsterdam</option>
        <option value="2">rotterdam</option>
        <option value="3">den haag</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="store" id="store" value="change city" />
</form>
<php
sql="get * from selected store"
foreach{item in selected store}{
    sql="get name for looped item"
    sql="get all admins"
    echo"all given info in td"
    if{the item has not been processed by a admin}{
        <from method="post">
            <select name="adminchange" onchange="submit()">
                <option value="null">not processed</option>
                foreach(for each admin make a option){
                    <option value="admin email">admin name</option>
                };
            </select>
        </form>
    }else{
        echo 'the name of the admin that processed it';
    };
};
 if (isset($_POST["chosen_admin"])) {
                $admin = the admin it was changed to;
                $productid = product where the admin was change;
                $sql = "UPDATE products SET admin = '$admin' WHERE product_id='$productid'";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();  
 };?>
```

and here is the code i'm using on my site(this is the real code so if you see the mistake plz tell me, also all tips are welcome because this is for a examen i am studing for.):

```
<form method="POST" >
    <select name="winkel">
        <option value="1">flowerpower amsterdam</option>
        <option value="2">flowerpower den Haag</option>
        <option value="3">flowerpower Rotterdam</option>
    </select>
     <input type="submit" name="store" id="submit" value="nu bestellen" />
     </form>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th><p>artikel</p></th>
            <th><p>aantal</p></th>
            <th><p>afhaler</p></th>
            <th><p>afhaal tijd</p></th>
            <th><p>afgehandeld door</p></th>
        </tr>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["store"])) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM verkocht WHERE locatie_ophalen = ". $_POST["winkel"] ;
    } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM verkocht WHERE locatie_ophalen = 1";
    }
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    foreach($result as $verkocht){
        $sql = "SELECT  product_naam FROM producten WHERE product_id = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($verkocht["product_id"]));
        $gegevens = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE medewerker = 1";
        $admins = $conn->query($sql);

        echo '<tr><td>'. $gegevens["product_naam"]. '</td>
        <td>'. $verkocht["verkocht_aantal"].'</td>
        <td>'. $verkocht["verkocht_klant"].'</td>
        <td>'.$verkocht["tijd_ophalen"].'</td>
        <td>';
        if($verkocht["medewerker_verwerkt"] == 0){
            echo'<form method="POST"><select name="chosen_admin" onchange="submit()">
            <option value="null">nog niet verwerkt</option>';
            foreach($admins as $admin){                   
            echo'<option value="'. $admin["email"].'">'. $admin["voornaam"].' '. $admin["achternaam"].'</option>';      
            };
        }else{
            echo $verkocht["medewerker_verwerkt"];
        };

            echo '</select></form>';
            echo '</td></tr>';
    };
 if (isset($_POST["chosen_admin"])) {
                $medewerker = $_POST["chosen_admin"];
                $verkoopid = $verkocht["verkocht_id"];
                $sql = "UPDATE verkocht SET medewerker_verwerkt = '$medewerker' WHERE verkocht_id='$verkoopid'";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();  
 };?>
</table>
```

Comment: what does `echo $sql` look like for the $sql in the last if-loop

Comment: Well your `$verkocht` variable is always referring to the last record you read from the database, so what result do you expect here?

Comment: And although in one place you are using prepared statements correctly, in all other places your code is wide open for SQL injection ...

Comment: @RST  UPDATE verkocht SET medewerker_verwerkt = '1@gmail.com' WHERE verkocht_id='26'

Comment: @CBroe yhea you are right, but it also only does the last one from the from the categorie that is standerd i see now. so mabby if i make it so that that the page dosn't reload it will work? mabby i think i need to use ajax for that right?

Comment: @CBroe but what if i send it with a ?productid=1&adminid=20 and then use getters to send that to the database, wouldnt that also work?